# Frame width has strange behaviour

Tags: iphone, uitableview, size, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to add a footer view to my gouped table view
for now i have this:

```
NSLog(@"width:%f",self.view.frame.size.width);
        UILabel *lblInfo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 30,self.view.frame.size.width - 100, 70)];
        lblInfo.text = @"Hellow";
        [footerView addSubview:lblInfo];
        [lblInfo release];
```

which give me this result: http://img256.imageshack.us/i/schermafbeelding2010102t.png/
This is landscape and self.view is an pushed subview of the detailview of my splitcontrol.
The nslog of the first: ->width: 703

If i turn (to portrait) it i get this result:http://img821.imageshack.us/i/schermafbeelding2010102.png/
The nslog of the second: -> width: 768

normally the two footer views should have a left & right margin of 50px...

What am i overseeing?

Answer (score 1):

You should set *autoresizingMask*:

```
lblInfo.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

You should also note to create the label with the footer's size:

```
UILabel *lblInfo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 30,footerView.frame.size.width - 100, 70)];
```

Comment: This is equivalent to what you'd do in Interface Builder, in the size section of the inspector.

Comment: wow didn't know that :) What is the | char? Is it the same like "or" ? I tried it but now i have this result: http://yfrog.com/5oschermafbeelding2010102p (so i am still not there)

Comment: Is _footerView_ the same width as _self.view_, in your example? When you create your label, try creating it with _footerView.frame.size.width - 100_ for width instead.

Comment: Just added: footerView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 30,self.view.frame.size.width - 100, 70); and still the same